# Why one routing protocol cannot handle the task of updating the routing table of all routers?

Tags: networking, routes

why going through intra and interdomain routing from my reference book ,i cannot understand a line which says that...
**Today , an internet can be so large that one routing protocol cannot handle the task of updating the routing table of all routers**
i just want to know Why one routing protocol cann't do that?
thanks in advance

Comment: I assume that means one IGP (Interior Gateway Protocol) cannot handle the task, and that is correct. BGP is an EGP (Exterior Gateway Protocol), and it runs the Internet. Most routers are blissfully ignorant of the full Internet routing table. Routers which have the full Internet routing table are fast router with a lot of RAM. Even those are limited to the Internet routes, which have a prefix length of a maximum of `/24` for IPv4 and `/48` for IPv6. Advertising larger prefixes would be nearly impossible due to the size of the routing table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what exactly your question is. But I will try this one ..

Internet has only one routing protocol and that's **BGP** and it can handle all world's traffic very well.

And All rest routing protocol are used in organizations by their best fit..

eg. **OPF, IGRP, EIGRP, ISIS.**